# CSS3 multicoulmn horizontal scrolling bug

Tags: jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

There seems to be some bug with horizontal column-layouts wrt scrolling.
I implemented 2 techniques for scrolling horizontally, but with both scrolling stops as you progressively move towards right. It can be only re-initiated if the mouse is moved over any content, text or image.

http://codepen.io/arjunmenon/pen/ZYZadQ
http://codepen.io/arjunmenon/pen/wBZPRN

Thanks.

```
PS - Tested on Chrome and Firefox in Debian.
```

Comment: This is also evident in other examples around the web - http://www.kaikkonendesign.fi/columns/.  Move the mouse near the top grey bar or bottom scrollbar. Please note, if the mouse is **on** the top bar, there is no issue with scrolling, only when it is between the top bar and the upper text, issue reveals.

Comment: You should post the relevant markup that re-creates this directly in the question... hence the big red: "Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code".